# Server.UrlEncode in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, web-services

I currently send data using x-www-form-urlencoded . Below is an Example that works.

```
sb.Append("&county=" & Server.UrlEncode(app.County))
```

Now i am having an issue using it when i have to select a Case.Example :

```
Select Case app.IncomeSource
                                Case ISFullTime
                    sb.Append("&employmentType=Full Time" & Server.UrlEncode(app.IncomeSource))
End Select
```

What it outputs is : Full+Timefull+time (The full+time in lowercase i assume is the actual value of app.IncomeSource.

How do i get it use only the data i specify "Full Time" using Url.encode

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
Select Case app.IncomeSource
  Case ISFullTime
    sb.Append("&employmentType=" & Server.UrlEncode("Full Time" & app.IncomeSource))
End Select
```

It should encode the whole value.

or if the value you want to receive is "Full Time" just use the following:

```
Select Case app.IncomeSource
  Case ISFullTime
    sb.Append("&employmentType=" & Server.UrlEncode("Full Time"))
End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `Server.UrlEncode` to convert (textual) data to a form suitable for use in a URL.

But you use [`Server.UrlDecode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to convert it back.

Comment: I what it does, i need a different way to write : sb.Append("&employmentType=Full Time" & Server.UrlEncode(app.IncomeSource)).

Comment: @user3703522 OK, your question could be clearer. Note spaces (as in your string literal) also need URL encoding.